# how to get biorthogonal wavelet matrix for compressed sensing

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am working in compressed sensing problem. Here I would like to find out the transform matrix of biorthogonal wavelet.

By this I mean that if I multiply with that matrix with my input signal I have to get the biorthogonal wavelet transform of the input. I know wavedec in matlab  will directly do this, but I would like to have separate matrix, for example suppose my input signal is 720 × 1 vector. I would like to have a biorthogonal matrix (W) that will multiply with input and give me the biorthogonal transform of my input vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the wavelet transform of the identity matrix. Most transform functions will let you input a matrix rather than a vector and then allow you to specify along which dimension to take the transform. So, for instance, take the wavelet transform of the identity matrix and tell the transform to operate down the columns. Otherwise, if you can't input a 2-D array, you can do it one vector at a time, where the first vector is [ 1; 0; 0; ... ], the second is [ 0; 1; 0; 0; ... ], and so on.

Comment: I think you didnt get what I am asking .I want to have the biorthogonal wavelet matrix ,which acts on the image/signal to produce the biorthogonal wavelet transfom

Comment: No, I understand exactly what you are asking and the above will give it to you. What exactly is it that you take issue with?